# Highchart does not load data from hidden input when using .val

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts, hidden-field

Here [is a JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jeryslo/79ymb/) of what I want to do. The data is not properly loaded, if I put [data directly](http://jsfiddle.net/jeryslo/4vne8/) then it works. Why is `$("#input").val()` not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are passing a string not an object, try this:

```
 data: $.parseJSON($("#input").val())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/79ymb/1/